# How to connect to adb server?

Tags: android, adb, android-sdk-tools

I'm trying to test out an adb honeypot, but adb wasn't connecting. So I tried `adb start-server` and this is what I got [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cg66S.png)

I installed it with "apt-get install and" so I could be missing some packages or something?

Error log:

```
daemon not running; starting now at tcp:5037
ADB server didn't ACK
Full server startup log: /tmp/adb.0.log
Server had pid: 3873547
--- adb starting (pid 3873547) ---
adb I 12-09 01:28:05 3873547 3873547 main.cpp:57] Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.39
adb I 12-09 01:28:05 3873547 3873547 main.cpp:57] Version 1:8.1.0+r23-8
adb I 12-09 01:28:05 3873547 3873547 main.cpp:57] Installed as /usr/lib/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb
adb I 12-09 01:28:05 3873547 3873547 main.cpp:57] 
adb I 12-09 01:28:05 3873547 3873547 adb_auth_host.cpp:416] adb_auth_init...
adb I 12-09 01:28:05 3873547 3873547 adb_auth_host.cpp:174] read_key_file '/root/.android/adbkey'...
munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer

* failed to start daemon
error: cannot connect to daemon
```

Comment: Please add text to [your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65209188/edit) as images are not searchable. You should also identify where (Linux version/real machine/virtual - CPU type) you are trying to run `adb`.

Comment: Fixed. And this is on Ubuntu, an actual one on digital ocean.

Comment: I believe Digital Ocean uses virtual machines (reference to virtual CPUs for droplets). Related: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/how-do-i-connect-a-usb-port-to-a-droplet-vm

Comment: Then what should I do?